# Solr Multicore Admin Problem

Tags: security, websphere, solr, http-status-code-404

Im trying to add a url based security constraint to solr deployed in websphere 6.1. If I specify the core name in the url of the constraint then the admin url for that core gives a 404. Has anyone had any success with this or any suggestions? Cheers

Comment: try posting this on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

It has worked just fine for me for /select etc urls, but I am not 100% sure I ever tried the admin url though....

However, one thing I ran into that you might as well is that if you are dynamically creating cores, or renaming them, say for a backup, then your patterns breakdown.  Why oh why doesn't the servlet spec support * characters in patterns :-).

Because I had to define all the potential names of cores up front, I ended up just wrapping the entire app in a layer of auth and not using url based security constraints.